# How does this 'loop do' end?

Tags: ruby

I am rewriting a piece of Ruby code found on github.com into Javascript. I am not having any problems understanding the code, except for the part below. The question is: how does the 'loop do' end if there are no 'break's?

```
  def utf8_bytes(record_size, record_tag)
    Enumerator.new do |yielder|
      bits = compressed_bits record_size, record_tag
      loop do
        # Use the Huffman tree to decode the first character.
        node = tree_root
        while node < 0x100
          # p ['node', node]
          bit = bits.next
          # p ['bit', bit]
          node = (bit == 0) ? tree_left[node] : tree_right[node]
        end
        first_byte = node - 0x100
        # p ['utf8 start', first_byte]
        yielder << first_byte

        # The other characters are 10xxxxxx, where x'es are raw bits.
        2.upto utf8_char_bytes(first_byte) do
          byte = 0b10
          6.times do
            byte = (byte << 1) | bits.next
          end
          # p ['utf8 byte', byte]
          yielder << byte
        end
      end
    end
  end
```

**Update**

Thanks for all the answers, but unfortunatly I still don't understand what is really happening. If I understand correctly, it is like a bucket. Every time you put something into it, it is being processed. And 'loop do' is done as many times as there are bytes that are put into it.

The function is calles only once, like so:

```
  text = utf8_bytes(record_size, record_tag).to_a.pack('C*')
```

But this is inside a Enumerator as well, so I guess the bytes drip from one bucket into the other.

In any case. I have translated the function into Javascript. Maybe someone can tell me if this is correct? (leaving aside that the Javascript function returns an array, and leaving aside that using arrays like this is probably not very inefficient)

```
    function utf8_bytes( record_size, record_tag ) {
        var yielder = new Array();
        bits = compressed_bits( record_size, record_tag );
// compressed_bits returns an array of 0's and 1's
        var v=0;
        while( v<bits.length ) {
//              # Use the Huffman tree to decode the first character.
            var node = tree_root;
            while ( node < 0x100 ) {
//                  # p ['node', node]
                bit = bits[v++];
//                  # p ['bit', bit]
                node = (bit == 0) ? tree_left[node] : tree_right[node];
            }
            var first_byte = node - 0x100;
//              # p ['utf8 start', first_byte]
            yielder.push( first_byte );

//              # The other characters are 10xxxxxx, where x'es are raw bits.
            for (var m=2; m<=utf8_char_bytes(first_byte); m++ ){
                var mbyte = 2;
                for (var n=0; n<6; n++ ) {
                    mbyte = (mbyte << 1) | bits[v++];
                }
//                  # p ['utf8 byte', mbyte]
                yielder.push( mbyte );
            }
        }
        return( yielder );
    }
```

Comment: Maybe it has something to do with 'bits.next'? That seems logical

Answer (score 1):

It appears to be an enumerator (Note the `Enumerator.new do |yielder|`.)  My guess is control flow returns every time the append operator (`<<`) is applied to `yielder`.

Comment: Not sure I understand what you mean.

Comment: The algorithm never ends.  However it does not run continuously.  Each `yielder << X` line is like a `return`, except that when the calling code comes back to get the next element, it picks up from that same spot.

Answer (score 1):

In `Enumerator::Yielder`, the `yield` method is aliased as `<<`.  So calling:

```
yielder << some_byte
```

is the same as:

```
yielder.yield some_byte
```

Calling `yield` blocks the control flow.  Control can return when `next` (or an equivalent c function) is called on the Enumerator object.  If `next` is never called, the loop will not continue, and will remain in that state until the Enumerator falls out of scope and is garbage collected.

You can read up on the [`Enumerator`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Enumerator.html) class for more info.

Comment: But how does that make the loop end?

Comment: The loop doesn't have to end - its execution is blocked by `yield`. Updated to clarify this point.

Answer (score 0):

The loop never ends by itself, i.e. this method returns an infinite enumerator.

```
utf8_bytes(...).to_a # => never ends
```

These can be very useful, as the block you call them with can return before consuming the whole (infinite) enumerator:

```
def foo
  utf8_bytes(...).each do |byte|
    return byte if is_it_what_youre_looking_for?(byte)
  end
  # You'll never get here!
end
```

In a similar fashion, is useful to get just a couple of values. For example:

```
utf8_bytes(...).first(100) # => array of length 100
```

To play around with a simpler "infinite" enumerator, you can use `0..Float::INFINITY` instead of calling `utf8_bytes`.

Comment: Thanks for explaining but I may have been a bit unclear about the fact that I don't know anything about Ruby.